# Is there a way to add a "select all" check box in a dataTable that checks all the checkboxs in the following table rows

Tags: jquery, node.js, datatable, datatables

I have multiple dynamic tables on my page, Each row has a checkbox that I'm assigining a value which I'm getting from an sql query. Attaching a screenshot below :-

[An example at two dynamic tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NGlI.png)

There can be more than 5-10 tables at times.

Here's my handlebars code for the table structure

```
<div id="collapse_{{major_location_id}}" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading data-parent="#accordion">
                             <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="common_table table-responsive search-input tablecolumnLimit">
                                   <table class="table  locations-table">
                                      <thead>
                                         <tr>
                                            <th>
                                               <label class="custom_checkbox">
                                                  <input class="chk_all" type="checkbox">
                                                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                               </label>Location Name
                                            </th>
                                            <th>Address</th>
                                            <th>City</th>
                                            <th>Zipcode</th>
                                         </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                         {{#each locations}}

                                         <tr>
                                            <td>
                                               <label class="custom_checkbox">
                                                  {{#if (eq type 'participant')}}
                                                  <input type="checkbox" class="chk_cls"
                                                     name="participant_locations[]" value="{{location_id}}">
                                                  {{else}}
                                                  <input type="checkbox" class="chk_cls"
                                                     name="non_participant_locations[]" value="{{location_id}}">
                                                  {{/if}}
                                                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                               </label>{{location_name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{this.address1}}</td>
                                            <td>{{this.donor_city}}</td>
                                            <td>{{this.zip}}</td>
                                         </tr>
                                         {{/each}}
                                      </tbody>
                                   </table>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
```

Here's my script for the datatable.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     //          var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;

     var table = $('.locations-table').dataTable();

     $(".chk_all").on('click', function () {
        /* I want to check all the checkboxes that exists in the table which **this** button 
           belongs to. Keeping in mind the hidden checkboxes due to pagination.
     });
```

)};

Following code works for just a single table :

```
$("#chk_all").on('click', function () {
    var cells = table.api().cells().nodes();
    $(cells).find('.chk_cls').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same [DataTables API](https://datatables.net/reference/type/DataTables.Api#API-structure) that you are already using, but just provide a different selector - for example:

```
var cells = $('.dataTable').dataTable().api().cells().nodes();
```

This finds all tables which use the class `dataTable`. From there, you can use the rest of your existing logic.

Answer (score 1):

Following modification in the suggestion given by Andrew worked for me.
I used $(this) to find the nearest table to my Check All checkbox and then used the variable to get all the cells.

```
$(".chk_all").on('click', function () {
     var myTable = $(this).closest(table);
     var cells = $(myTable).dataTable().api().cells().nodes();
     $(cells).find('.chk_cls').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```